# How to load xml through http proxy objective c?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

I developing very basic program for mac. The program read xml file using NSXMLParser with NSURLConnection. I need to load URL using **http proxy server** (not system proxy). Is anyone knows how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "using proxy server" here? In many cases, your app should not need to know or care if requests are going through a proxy server. However, some proxy configurations may implement certain restrictions or other requirements, so without knowing specifically what you are dealing with it is hard to answer.

Comment: I using http proxy without authentication

Comment: Unless there is something else about this you are not mentioning, the fact that you are going through an HTTP proxy server is probably irrelevant. Make a URL request as documented in the NSURLConnection documentation. If there is a problem introduced by the fact you are using a proxy, please me more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I need to make multiple connections through different http proxies using ip:port addresses to read xml file(s) from the web.

Comment: There's nothing special about HTTP proxies here: If you need to retrieve from specific IP/port addresses just put them in the URL. For example, http://192.168.0.30:100/myXmlFile.xml would get you to an HTTP server (proxy or not) sitting on port 100 at 192.168.0.30

Comment: In this example you have 192.168.0.30:100/myXmlFile.xml laying on this server. What if file laying on www.yahoo.com/myXmlFile.xml? Can I use following scheme: 192.168.0.30:100/http://www.yahoo.com/notMyXmlFile.xml Sorry, I have no network experience. Thanks.

Comment: That is not how proxies typically work, but I suppose it is possible if configured that way. They key point is that there is nothing special to do from an objective-C perspective to do here. You need to figure out what URL's to use to access what you want through the proxy, and specify those URL's when creating the NSURL. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out [the docs for NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), they will tell you that you need to implement the callback methods in the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol, and will give you details.

That page also points to several examples, with sample code.

You can also check out the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) at developer.apple.com, which will give you additional information on how these classes can be used.

Comment: I checked NSURLConnection delegate protocol, however I don't see any ways I can connect through http proxy. Can it be lower level like Core Foundation? Thank you.